# Deploying *.war application with Java Web Start (JNLP)

Tags: java, tomcat6, jnlp, java-web-start

I want to rollout a web application (*.war) with Java Web Start (JNLP). My starting condition is that I have a running configured Tomcat 6.0 server available at the client.
Normal deployment at tomcat is pretty clear to me. Just put the *.war file to the webapps folder and restart tomcat - finished.

If I want to the same with JNLP it looks somehow complicated. I was thinking about the following JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- JNLP File for JimageConnect.com JTwacker Application -->
  <jnlp codebase="file:///local_installer">
<information>
   <title>War deployment</title>
   <vendor>Vendor</vendor>
   <description>long </description>
   <description kind="short">short</description>
  <offline-allowed/>
 </information>
 <security>
      <all-permissions/>
  </security>
 <resources>
   <jar href="deployment.jar"/>
   <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
 </resources>
 <application-desc main-class="com.vendor.deployment.Deploy" />
```

Where deployment.jar holds:

-) the *.war file which should be deployed

-) everything which is needed to use command line redeployment of web application descibed at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant

-) the class Deploy which reads the *.war as Stream from the classloader and executes an undeployment/deployment for tomcat.

That sollution should work but it looks hand made and somehow ugly. Is there a better solution available?

Comment: Why would you want to use webstart for deployment? If there has to be an existing Tomcat anyways, why don't you just require the user to deploy the application? And if it is for automatic updates, I'd try and look into other update mechanisms.

Comment: My Scenario looks like this: I have more than 8000 clients distributed over the whole country which have a running tomcat instance. All those clients might be behind a firewall, offline, whatever. So I think I do not have a possibility to deploy a web application directly. As I also rollout some other client functionallity (Swing GUI) via JNLP it was my first guess to use JNLP also for rolling out my web archives.

Comment: 1) The JNLP as shown is invalid.  2) JWS is for launching rich client apps., not web-apps. 3) JWS is capable of calling an installer (which might then install the `web-app`) but I doubt that would have any advantage over referring the user directly to the installer.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Maybe I should rephrase my question. I need a possibility to distribute a *.war file to different clients which have a running tomcat instance. The deployment of the *.war file should happen without user input. Because of that the solution with creating an MSI or whatever installer is not suffient. As the clients currently already uses a JNLP file to update their rich clients it was my first guess to use the same mechanism to update the web applications as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a customer installer which installed my Tomcat server and even handled UAC correctly.
A second tooling deployed my application if needed.